# Spring @Transactional propagation property

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I have a question about spring transaction propagation. I understand different Spring transaction propagation i.e. `Propagation.REQUIRED`, `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` etc. What I am not clear about is how would it behave in case of nested transactions with different propagation values.

For example If I use `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)` to annotate a method `m1`. If I call a method `m2` which is annotated as `REQUIRES_NEW`. What would be the behaviour? If an exception occurs in `m2` will it rollback the changes in `m2` and as well as `m1` or only the changes of `m1`.
Similarly `m1` annotated as `REQUIRES_NEW` and `m2` as `REQUIRED`.

Answer (score 1):

It's explained pretty well in the [spring documentation for Transaction Propagation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation).

The propagation behavior of a method defines how Spring behaves upon entry/exit of that method and what happens if a transaction already exists (or does not exist) at that time.

The propagation behaviors of methods up the stack (whatever is calling your method) are irrelevant.

For your examples:

Outer (m1): `REQUIRED`
Inner (m2): `REQUIRES_NEW`
Result: A completely separate transaction will be created for m2 which can commit/rollback separately. m1 having `REQUIRED` is not relevant to m2.

Outer (m1): `REQUIRES_NEW`
Inner (m2): `REQUIRED`
Result: Spring will check that a transaction exists upon entering m2 or create one if none exists.

Comment: Thanks takteek for providing the link to the spring documentation. I have already seen that link. I primarily looking at transaction behavior when two methods have different propagation levels. Taking your first example if I make some changes in method m1 and then called m2 what would happen if an exception occurs in m2. All the changes that were made in m2 would be roll back and what will happen to m1 changes. What happens if there is exception in m1. The changes of m2 would be committed or rollback.

Comment: With `REQUIRES_NEW` it's a separate physical transaction. An exception in m2 would cause the m2 transaction to rollback. As long as you stop that exception from being rethrown in m1, m1 can commit just fine. The propagation setting of m1 does not really matter to m2.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to explain this with an example and a more detailed explanation. I have searched over the web but I didn't find anywhere some examples around this. I think this is more or less a common use case to nest different propagation's but not enough information around.

Comment: Would appreciate if some one can explain this with an example.